# Running PlantUML with OpenJDK 8 on Mac OS

Tags: java, macos, freetype, plantuml

I can't run PlantUML with OpenJDK 8 on Mac OS. I downloaded version 1.8.0u192 from the AdoptOpenJDK site for macOS:

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_192"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_192-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.192-b12, mixed mode)
```

If I try to process a simple diagram with PlantUML I get the following error message:

```
$ java -jar plantuml.1.2018.14.jar example.puml
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /private/tmp/jdk8u192-b12/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libfontmanager.dylib: dlopen(/private/tmp/jdk8u192-b12/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libfontmanager.dylib, 1): Library not loaded: @rpath/libfreetype.6.dylib
Referenced from: /private/tmp/jdk8u192-b12/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libfontmanager.dylib
Reason: image not found
at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1845)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
at sun.font.FontManagerNativeLibrary$1.run(FontManagerNativeLibrary.java:61)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.font.FontManagerNativeLibrary.<clinit>(FontManagerNativeLibrary.java:32)
at sun.font.SunFontManager$1.run(SunFontManager.java:339)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.<clinit>(SunFontManager.java:335)
at sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.getMetrics(FontDesignMetrics.java:264)
at sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.getFontMetrics(SunGraphics2D.java:863)
at net.sourceforge.plantuml.Run.forceOpenJdkResourceLoad(Run.java:234)
at net.sourceforge.plantuml.Run.main(Run.java:143)
```

The error is independent of the diagram. I can't even process the most simple PlantUML diagram from the project homepage:

```
@startuml
Bob -> Alice : hello
@enduml
```

Obviously FreeType is missing. But how can I fix this?

Comment: I think id might be advantagious when you add (a small) example.puml to show the problem.

Comment: I downloaded Amazon's Corretto 8 JDK. It is able to process the diagram.

Comment: The reason might be the same as https://github.com/corretto/corretto-8/issues/6 for Amazon Corretto.